# How can I write an Expression to get an Item from an Array using an Array property value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, formula, power-platform

I have this flow :

[image]

Where I am building an array which contain those properties:

- ID
- SharingLink
- Password

then I am building an HTML table >> so how can I get the Array's SharingLink values inside the build HTML table based on the Array's ID values (`item()['ID']`)?

Comment: Use "Filter array" action and filter array based on the ID and then you can use first() function to get the SharingLink property value.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, you can use **Filter array** action to filter `SharingLinks` array based on the ID and then you can use `first()` function to get the `sharingLink` property value.

Here's example flow which will help you to get started with:

[image]

**Expressions used**:

**Filter array** action (left side expression for ID property):

```
@item()['ID']
```

**Compose** action:

```
@{first(body('Filter_array'))?['sharingLink']}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: i know that i can use Filter Array action, but i want to do the array filtering using an expression inside the Create HTML table as shown in the picture i provided. thanks

Comment: From which action's output are you getting the `ID` value? Also, there is no `filter` function available in flow expressions directly. So, it might not be possible to filter the array based on one property value and get another property's value using single expression.

Comment: Does this help you with your above queries?

Answer (score 0):

@microsoftdeveloperdesigner see this URL:
https://www.process.st/how-to/get-value-from-array-in-power-automate/
[image]

This limits how you can lookup the values to the array index as a key.

Additionally, this page may help you see how to lookup values within arrays from a json perspective:
https://tomriha.com/how-to-get-a-specific-value-from-a-json-object-in-power-automate/

Is this closer to what you wanted?